# USING collections in Android

Tags: java, android, json, collections

### I was looking at this code while surfing through Stackoverflow

**CODE::**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String NAME = "rank";
    static String TYPE = "country";
    static String DISTANCE = "distance";
    static String RATING = "rating";
    static String FLAG = "flag";
    static String PRICE= "price";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);


        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Fetching the information");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("--------------URL----------");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("ARRAY");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put(MainActivity.NAME, jsonobject.getString("collegeNAME"));
                    map.put(MainActivity.TYPE, jsonobject.getString("collegeTYPE"));
                    map.put(MainActivity.FLAG, jsonobject.getString("collegeIMAGE"));
                    map.put(MainActivity.DISTANCE, jsonobject.getString("collegeDISTANCE"));
                    map.put(MainActivity.RATING, jsonobject.getString("collegeRATING"));
                    map.put(MainActivity.PRICE, jsonobject.getString("collegePrice"));

                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

---

- My Question is Why we use collection in android ?
- What is the use ?
- Why a hashmap is added to ArrayList in the above code ?
- Can't we directly set views in android without collection,( I tried
  it dosent work when dealing with group of key,value pairs)

.
~ I am a newbie so please go easy on with answers to my questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to answer your first 2 questions about collections... but I'll give it a shot.

1, 2) Collections are good for keeping groups of information lumped together and accessible through 1 variable. They also make it very easy to iterate over them, which makes them ideal for things like ListView adapters since that is also a list (or a collection).

Consider the following if you dont have an array

```
String var1 = "hi1";
String var2 = "hi2";
String var3 = "hi3";
String var4 = "hi4";
String var5 = "hi5";
String var6 = "hi6";
String var7 = "hi7";
String var8 = "hi8";
String var9 = "hi9";

// do something with the variables    
Toast.makeText(this, var1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(this, var2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(this, var3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(this, var4, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(this, var5, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(this, var6, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(this, var7, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(this, var8, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(this, var9, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Now consider this, if you have arrays:

```
ArrayList<String> vars = new ArrayList<String(9);
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    vars.add("hi" + i);
    Toast.makeText(this, vars.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Much, much easier to work with.

3) The Hashmap is added to the array because the author wanted to keep a collection of separate name/value pairs.  *You can't have multiple keys with the same value in a Hashmap*, so if you want that then you have to make a new Hashmap. The adding them to an array was to keep it neat, and then allowed the author to pass the array to a ListView adapter for displaying the values to the user using Android's built-in mechanism.

Basically the author created this Hierarchy:

```
item1
    name
    type
    flag
    distance
    rating
    price
item2
    name
    type
    flag
    distance
    rating
    price
item3
    name
    type
    flag
    distance
    rating
    price
...etc...
```

So when the ListView iterated over the array, each separate collection of hashmap values will be available to a new listview item for displaying.

4) You can set values directly, but working with adapters in ListViews makes it much less of a chore. You create an array, pass the array to the listview, and bada-bing-bada-boom, there's your list. Otherwise you will be creating ListView items and setting the display text all yourself for each item.  In a similar way to why collections are useful when you have many variables of the same type, passing that collection to a ListView makes it much, much easier to code, maintain, and troubleshoot, not to mention that it just works!

I hope this helps!  We are all beginners once :)

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will go populate an ListView, there are several ways to do that. I believe in this case, the coder is SimpleAdapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html.

Some think like:

```
// In This case the value os NAME is shown on android.R.id.text1 (TextView)
// and PRICE is shown on android.R.id.text2 (TextView)
String[] from = new String[]{MainActivity.NAME, MainActivity.PRICE}; // Map keys
int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}; // List Layout item views

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, arraylist, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, String[] from, int[] to);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```